# How to analyze and debug a Linux kernel panic which occurs while running an application?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, panic, nxp-microcontroller

I'm getting kernel panics while running linux application on my custom hardware design. But another custom hardware which is similar to this can run this linux application without any problem. I did the memory calibration and stress app test for this board. But there was not any issue related to memory. So how can I debug this to clarify whether this is hardware or software problem. I could debug kernel and uboot using JTAG properly. But how can I pinpoint the issue for this kernel panic while running certain application ?

**Here is the panic message (LOG)**

```
[ 308.268356] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 
54494156
[ 308.275647] pgd = 80004000
[ 308.278365] [54494156] *pgd=00000000
[ 308.281977] Internal error: Oops: 80000005 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[ 308.287904] Modules linked in: tw6869 mxc_v4l2_capture ipu_bg_overlay_sdc 
ipu_still ipu_prp_enc videobuf2_dma_contig ipu_csi_enc videobuf2_memops 
adv7610_video ipu_fg_overlay_sdc v4l2_int_device galcore(O)
[ 308.306375] CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Tainted: G O 4.1.15-2.0.0- 
ga+yocto+gff4e28b #1
[ 308.309584] tw6869 0000:01:00.0: tw6869_querystd: vch1: unknown std 
detected
[ 308.322648] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
[ 308.329184] task: ce11bc00 ti: ce14c000 task.ti: ce14c000
[ 308.334598] PC is at 0x54494156
[ 308.337766] LR is at cpuidle_enter_state+0x90/0x350
[ 308.342650] pc : [<54494156>] lr : [<806d59b0>] psr: 800b00b3
[ 308.342650] sp : ce14df30 ip : 00000017 fp : ce14df8c
[ 308.354132] r10: 80e02508 r9 : 80e08ad0 r8 : 80d9b880
[ 308.359361] r7 : 00000001 r6 : 80e88160 r5 : 00000047 r4 : c04b271c
[ 308.365892] r3 : 54494157 r2 : 00000000 r1 : 80e08a80 r0 : 80d9b880
[ 308.372430] Flags: Nzcv IRQs off FIQs on Mode SVC_32 ISA Thumb Segment 
kernel
[ 308.380004] Control: 10c5387d Table: 5f38404a DAC: 00000015
[ 308.385755] Process swapper/3 (pid: 0, stack limit = 0xce14c210)
[ 308.391768] Stack: (0xce14df30 to 0xce14e000)
[ 308.396135] df20: 00000000 d0f2c140 c04b271c 00000047
[ 308.404333] df40: 00000000 00000000 004832f1 00000000 c04b271c 00000047 
00000000 dc8ba30f
[ 308.412537] df60: 80d97320 ce14c000 80e025e8 80e88160 d0f2bed0 80e08a74 
80a02970 ce14dfa0
[ 308.420738] df80: ce14df9c ce14df90 806d5cc0 806d592c ce14dfdc ce14dfa0 
80171a74 806d5ca8
[ 308.428939] dfa0: 80d9b880 80d9b880 00000000 80e02e00 80e025f0 80e878ea 
00000001 80c09164
[ 308.437140] dfc0: 80d9aec8 80d97300 10c0387d 80e8d35c ce14dff4 ce14dfe0 
8010fae0 801717d8
[ 308.445340] dfe0: 5e12c06a 00000015 00000000 ce14dff8 1010162c 8010f994 
00000000 00000000
[ 308.453529] Backtrace:
[ 308.456036] [<806d5920>] (cpuidle_enter_state) from [<806d5cc0>] 
(cpuidle_enter+0x24/0x28)
[ 308.464320] r10:ce14dfa0 r9:80a02970 r8:80e08a74 r7:d0f2bed0 r6:80e88160 
r5:80e025e8
[ 308.472277] r4:ce14c000
[ 308.474868] [<806d5c9c>] (cpuidle_enter) from [<80171a74>] 
(cpu_startup_entry+0x2a8/0x43c)
[ 308.483171] [<801717cc>] (cpu_startup_entry) from [<8010fae0>] 
(secondary_start_kernel+0x158/0x164)
[ 308.492232] r7:80e8d35c
[ 308.494813] [<8010f988>] (secondary_start_kernel) from [<1010162c>] 
(0x1010162c)
[ 308.502223] r5:00000015 r4:5e12c06a
[ 308.505862] Code: bad PC value
[ 308.508940] ---[ end trace 1d6a0d2b2019793f ]---
[ 308.513579] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task!
[ 308.520313] CPU1: stopping
[ 308.523060] CPU: 1 PID: 37 Comm: cfinteractive Tainted: G D O 4.1.15- 
2.0.0-ga+yocto+gff4e28b #1
[ 308.532731] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
[ 308.539274] Backtrace:
[ 308.541792] [<8010c358>] (dump_backtrace) from [<8010c5d4>] 
(show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[ 308.549379] r7:80e87b48 r6:80e45ca0 r5:00000000 r4:80e45ca0
[ 308.555168] [<8010c5b4>] (show_stack) from [<80919780>] 
(dump_stack+0x7c/0xbc)
[ 308.562421] [<80919704>] (dump_stack) from [<80110038>] 
(handle_IPI+0x2e4/0x2f8)
[ 308.569831] r7:80e87b48 r6:00000005 r5:80d99c34 r4:80d99c34
[ 308.575608] [<8010fd54>] (handle_IPI) from [<80101594>] 
(gic_handle_irq+0x68/0x6c)
[ 308.583192] r10:00000002 r9:ce020000 r8:00000001 r7:f4a00100 r6:ce321b28 
r5:80e02f7c
[ 308.591152] r4:f4a0010c r3:ce321b28
[ 308.594795] [<8010152c>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<8010d240>] 
(__irq_svc+0x40/0x74)
[ 308.602295] Exception stack(0xce321b28 to 0xce321b70)
[ 308.607371] 1b20: 00000001 80bbbbd4 80e8f9c0 00000000 ffffe000 80e8f9c0
[ 308.615572] 1b40: 00000010 00000000 00000001 ce020000 00000002 ce321bd4 
ce321b60 ce321b70
[ 308.623769] 1b60: 80493dc0 80137668 200f0113 ffffffff
[ 308.628833] r7:ce321b5c r6:ffffffff r5:200f0113 r4:80137668
[ 308.634617] [<801375b4>] (__do_softirq) from [<80137c20>] 
(irq_exit+0xd0/0x10c)
[ 308.641940] r10:ce321c40 r9:ce020000 r8:00000001 r7:00000000 r6:00000010 
r5:00000000
[ 308.649901] r4:80d99c34
[ 308.652491] [<80137b50>] (irq_exit) from [<8017beb4>] 
(__handle_domain_irq+0x90/0xfc)
[ 308.660335] r5:00000000 r4:80d99c34
[ 308.663984] [<8017be24>] (__handle_domain_irq) from [<80101560>] 
(gic_handle_irq+0x34/0x6c)
[ 308.672348] r10:00000004 r9:ce321d90 r8:00000001 r7:f4a00100 r6:ce321c40 
r5:80e02f7c
[ 308.680311] r4:f4a0010c r3:ce321c40
[ 308.683954] [<8010152c>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<8010d240>] 
(__irq_svc+0x40/0x74)
[ 308.691453] Exception stack(0xce321c40 to 0xce321c88)
[ 308.696528] 1c40: 00000003 d0f2f89c 00000003 00000003 80e02650 d0f13180 
80e02e00 d0f13184
[ 308.704729] 1c60: 00000001 ce321d90 00000004 ce321cbc 00000003 ce321c88 
801a739c 801a73cc
[ 308.712923] 1c80: 200f0013 ffffffff
[ 308.716425] r7:ce321c74 r6:ffffffff r5:200f0013 r4:801a73cc
[ 308.722208] [<801a715c>] (smp_call_function_many) from [<801a7468>] 
(smp_call_function+0x48/0x88)
[ 308.731093] r10:ffffffff r9:ce321d88 r8:00000000 r7:00000000 r6:00000001 
r5:ce321d90
[ 308.739054] r4:80110990
[ 308.741634] [<801a7420>] (smp_call_function) from [<801a74e0>] 
(on_each_cpu+0x38/0x90)
[ 308.749564] r7:00000000 r6:00000001 r5:ce321d90 r4:80110990
[ 308.755342] [<801a74a8>] (on_each_cpu) from [<80110d2c>] 
(twd_rate_change+0x38/0x40)
[ 308.763099] r7:00000000 r6:00000002 r5:ce321d88 r4:ffffffff
[ 308.768890] [<80110cf4>] (twd_rate_change) from [<801523c4>] 
(notifier_call_chain+0x54/0x94)
[ 308.777357] [<80152370>] (notifier_call_chain) from [<80152894>] 
(__srcu_notifier_call_chain+0x54/0x70)
[ 308.786763] r9:ce321d88 r8:00000002 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:ce0a6184 
r4:ce0a619c
[ 308.794650] [<80152840>] (__srcu_notifier_call_chain) from [<801528d8>] 
(srcu_notifier_call_chain+0x28/0x30)
[ 308.804491] r10:00000000 r9:80e8a384 r8:00000002 r7:80e02508 r6:ce026000 
r5:80e73b44
[ 308.812451] r4:ce0a6180
[ 308.815042] [<801528b0>] (srcu_notifier_call_chain) from [<80746114>] 
(__clk_notify+0xa0/0xa8)
[ 308.823683] [<80746074>] (__clk_notify) from [<807461c4>] 
(__clk_recalc_rates+0xa8/0xac)
[ 308.831786] r8:ce003f80 r7:00000001 r6:1daee080 r5:00000002 r4:ce026000
[ 308.838630] [<8074611c>] (__clk_recalc_rates) from [<80746198>] 
(__clk_recalc_rates+0x7c/0xac)
[ 308.847254] r7:00000001 r6:3b5dc100 r5:00000002 r4:ce026000
[ 308.853030] [<8074611c>] (__clk_recalc_rates) from [<80746198>] 
(__clk_recalc_rates+0x7c/0xac)
[ 308.861654] r7:00000001 r6:3b5dc100 r5:00000002 r4:ce026a80
[ 308.867438] [<8074611c>] (__clk_recalc_rates) from [<80748b50>] 
(clk_core_set_parent+0x1bc/0x2dc)
[ 308.876324] r7:00000001 r6:00000000 r5:ce026380 r4:ce026400
[ 308.882102] [<80748994>] (clk_core_set_parent) from [<80748c9c>] 
(clk_set_parent+0x2c/0x30)
[ 308.890467] r9:00000000 r8:179a7b00 r7:80e02508 r6:000f32a0 r5:00060ae0 
r4:80eec6ac
[ 308.898357] [<80748c70>] (clk_set_parent) from [<806d4220>] 
(imx6q_set_target+0x490/0x544)
[ 308.906653] [<806d3d90>] (imx6q_set_target) from [<806ca034>] 
(__cpufreq_driver_target+0x184/0x2b0)
[ 308.915712] r10:00000000 r9:00000000 r8:80eec5e4 r7:00000000 r6:80e02508 
r5:ce66b500
[ 308.923671] r4:00000000
[ 308.926253] [<806c9eb0>] (__cpufreq_driver_target) from [<806d2d44>] 
(cpufreq_interactive_speedchange_task+0x264/0x354)
[ 308.937048] r10:80d9ae10 r9:80e02650 r8:80e02e00 r7:00000000 r6:000f32a0 
r5:80d9ae10
[ 308.945007] r4:d0f1ee10
[ 308.947591] [<806d2ae0>] (cpufreq_interactive_speedchange_task) from 
[<801514e4>] (kthread+0xfc/0x114)
[ 308.956911] r10:00000000 r9:00000000 r8:00000000 r7:806d2ae0 r6:00000000 
r5:ce303480
[ 308.964870] r4:00000000
[ 308.967456] [<801513e8>] (kthread) from [<80108028>] 
(ret_from_fork+0x14/0x2c)
[ 308.974692] r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:801513e8 r4:ce303480
[ 308.980460] CPU0: stopping
[ 308.983202] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G D O 4.1.15-2.0.0- 
ga+yocto+gff4e28b #1
[ 308.992439] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
[ 308.998981] Backtrace:
[ 309.001488] [<8010c358>] (dump_backtrace) from [<8010c5d4>] 
(show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[ 309.009073] r7:80e87b48 r6:80e45ca0 r5:00000000 r4:80e45ca0
[ 309.014859] [<8010c5b4>] (show_stack) from [<80919780>] 
(dump_stack+0x7c/0xbc)
[ 309.022112] [<80919704>] (dump_stack) from [<80110038>] 
(handle_IPI+0x2e4/0x2f8)
[ 309.029522] r7:80e87b48 r6:00000005 r5:80d99c34 r4:80d99c34
[ 309.035298] [<8010fd54>] (handle_IPI) from [<80101594>] 
(gic_handle_irq+0x68/0x6c)
[ 309.042881] r10:80e02508 r9:80e08b14 r8:d0f04ed0 r7:f4a00100 r6:80e01e98 
r5:80e02f7c
[ 309.050843] r4:f4a0010c r3:80e01e98
[ 309.054488] [<8010152c>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<8010d240>] 
(__irq_svc+0x40/0x74)
[ 309.061987] Exception stack(0x80e01e98 to 0x80e01ee0)
[ 309.067058] 1e80: 00000000 d0f084c0
[ 309.075261] 1ea0: dc8ba30f dc8ba30f cef8dbc4 00000047 80e88160 00000004 
d0f04ed0 80e08b14
[ 309.083462] 1ec0: 80e02508 80e01f3c 80e01e80 80e01ee0 8091f2bc 806d59e0 
600f0013 ffffffff
[ 309.091652] r7:80e01ecc r6:ffffffff r5:600f0013 r4:806d59e0
[ 309.097430] [<806d5920>] (cpuidle_enter_state) from [<806d5cc0>] 
(cpuidle_enter+0x24/0x28)
[ 309.105708] r10:80e01f50 r9:80a02970 r8:80e08a74 r7:d0f04ed0 r6:80e88160 
r5:80e025e8
[ 309.113667] r4:80e00000
[ 309.116248] [<806d5c9c>] (cpuidle_enter) from [<80171a74>] 
(cpu_startup_entry+0x2a8/0x43c)
[ 309.124540] [<801717cc>] (cpu_startup_entry) from [<80917448>] 
(rest_init+0x98/0x9c)
[ 309.132297] r7:80e02500
[ 309.134893] [<809173b0>] (rest_init) from [<80d00d9c>] 
(start_kernel+0x404/0x424)
[ 309.142390] r5:80e8d000 r4:80e8d04c
[ 309.146037] [<80d00998>] (start_kernel) from [<1000807c>] (0x1000807c)
[ 309.152583] CPU2: stopping
[ 309.155327] CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Tainted: G D O 4.1.15-2.0.0- 
ga+yocto+gff4e28b #1
[ 309.164565] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
[ 309.171106] Backtrace:
[ 309.173611] [<8010c358>] (dump_backtrace) from [<8010c5d4>] 
(show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[ 309.181196] r7:80e87b48 r6:80e45ca0 r5:00000000 r4:80e45ca0
[ 309.186977] [<8010c5b4>] (show_stack) from [<80919780>] 
(dump_stack+0x7c/0xbc)
[ 309.194230] [<80919704>] (dump_stack) from [<80110038>] 
(handle_IPI+0x2e4/0x2f8)
[ 309.201639] r7:80e87b48 r6:00000005 r5:80d99c34 r4:80d99c34
[ 309.207417] [<8010fd54>] (handle_IPI) from [<80101594>] 
(gic_handle_irq+0x68/0x6c)
[ 309.215001] r10:80e02508 r9:80e08b14 r8:d0f1eed0 r7:f4a00100 r6:ce14bee8 
r5:80e02f7c
[ 309.222960] r4:f4a0010c r3:ce14bee8
[ 309.226604] [<8010152c>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<8010d240>] 
(__irq_svc+0x40/0x74)
[ 309.234103] Exception stack(0xce14bee8 to 0xce14bf30)
[ 309.239179] bee0: 00000000 d0f224c0 dc8ba30f dc8ba30f ce933307 00000047
[ 309.247383] bf00: 80e88160 00000004 d0f1eed0 80e08b14 80e02508 ce14bf8c 
ce14bed0 ce14bf30
[ 309.255578] bf20: 8091f2bc 806d59e0 600f0013 ffffffff
[ 309.260643] r7:ce14bf1c r6:ffffffff r5:600f0013 r4:806d59e0
[ 309.266420] [<806d5920>] (cpuidle_enter_state) from [<806d5cc0>] 
(cpuidle_enter+0x24/0x28)
[ 309.274698] r10:ce14bfa0 r9:80a02970 r8:80e08a74 r7:d0f1eed0 r6:80e88160 
r5:80e025e8
[ 309.282656] r4:ce14a000
[ 309.285237] [<806d5c9c>] (cpuidle_enter) from [<80171a74>] 
(cpu_startup_entry+0x2a8/0x43c)
[ 309.293528] [<801717cc>] (cpu_startup_entry) from [<8010fae0>] 
(secondary_start_kernel+0x158/0x164)
[ 309.302587] r7:80e8d35c
[ 309.305168] [<8010f988>] (secondary_start_kernel) from [<1010162c>] 
(0x1010162c)
[ 309.312579] r5:00000015 r4:5e12c06a
[ 309.316221] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the 
idle task!
```

I must be thankful to you if you can guide me on this issue. Are there any methods for hardware debugging to pinpoint the issues related to this while running applications on linux ?

Regards,
Kulunu.

Comment: Usually means "we have wrong address in pointer and can't find it"
It can be a result of memory corruption
First ( I assume, that you have source code for your linux application ) determine, which system call corrupts memory ( you can achieve it by logging all steps to some COM-port ).
- if your application have personal kernel module - bug probably here;
- if application doesn't have additional kernel module, then you have bug in some driver in your kernel. That complicates things - you will need to rebuild kernel with debugging options and try to catch this error in kernel source code

Comment: All steps above are for software problem. Hardware problem can be detected by special tests like Ubuntu System Testing and others

Comment: Thank Roman I already used Stress app test and Memory stress test tools to verify my hardware memory and I didn't get any error from those tests. When I'm running this application some custom boards fails with Kernel panics and some are working properly. 1) Can you suggest me Ubuntu system testing tool or any other tool as you have mentioned ? 2) I'm presently using GDB for back trace the crashes like Segmentation faults. But when Kernel panic happened I can't access the kernel and all the system get sucked. Do you have any idea to analyze this type of panic information to understandable way ?

Comment: 1) Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/389084/system-testing-tool-for-ubuntu 2) As I said you will need to recompile kernel with some debug config options and then redirect dmesg to some COM-port because when panic occurs - all user-space freezes ( so ssh / gdb will just stop working ). But first - determine, which system call from your application makes kernel panic